# How to show translations using Angular-Translate?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Angular-translate in combination with partial-loader only shows the key and not the actual translation. I've tried everything but can't seem to locate the mistake. No errors are logged.

This is my code:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'appRoutes', 
  'pascalprecht.translate',
  'angularTranslate',
  'HomeCtrl'
]); 

angular.module('angularTranslate', ['pascalprecht.translate'])
  .config(function($translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider ) {
    $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
      urlTemplate: '/languages/{lang}/{part}.json'
    });

  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('nl');

});
```

So the templates are loaded from /languages/{lang}/{part}.json

**HomeCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('HomeCtrl', []).controller('HomeController', 
  function($scope, $translate, $translatePartialLoader) {

    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('home');
    $translate.refresh();

});
```

In Express I have this route to ensure that the files are actually returned instead of routed to Angular:

```
app.get('/languages/:lang/:part', function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile(req.params.lang + '/' + req.params.part, { root: '././languages' });
});
```

**home.json**

```
{
    "HOMETITLE" : "Geweldige Whatsapp gesprekken.",
}
```

**home.html**

```
{{ "HOMETITLE" || translate }}
```

And finally I have linked everything in index.html using this order:

```
<script src="../libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../libs/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../libs/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="../libs/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="../libs/angular-translate-loader-partial/angular-translate-loader-partial.js"></script>

<script src="../js/controllers/HomeCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="../js/appRoutes.js"></script>
<script src="../js/index.js"></script>
```

So to restate my problem: only HOMETITLE is displayed instead of the correct translation. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could it be possible to isolate this in a plunkr? I think this could help to pinpoint where is the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my experience with angular translate a few different issues could be happening here which is hard to pin down because your environment plays a factor into this, if you had a github repo I could clone I could be certain.

1. You just have a formatting problem on your translate like one of the other people have stated,  {{ "HOMETITLE" | translate }}  You can see here for other possible ways of formatting the translation.  I have run into issues using the filter translation with partial and external file loading, I would strongly recommend if you are going to be using partial loading then you only use attributes for setting your translations  such as

   http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/05_using-translate-directive
2. Your partial file loader is running into a race condition and it is resolving the {{ "HOMETITLE" | translate }} before you actually get the translations back.  Since you can use default translations with partial loading I would suggest putting in a default translation in your translate provider config to make sure that is not the case.  Something as simple as what some of the other users have described as

   ```
   $translateProvider.translations('nl', {
     "HOMETITLE" : "Geweldige Whatsapp gesprekken.",
   });

   $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('nl');
   $translateProvider.forceAsyncReload(true);
   ```

Adding translateProvider.forceAsyncReload(true); to the end of the config will force a refresh.  However I would recommend that you make the translation slightly different then the json file so you can see if that is the case before adding the force reload.

Comment: Thanks James! I did have a formatting error. When I solved that it still didn't work because of the race condition (I verified). How can I track / prevent / solve that? Thanks again!

Comment: So I have had this happen a number of times when loading partial translations from another file.  There are a few issues partaking to this in the angular-translate backlog.  The best thing I can say is wrap the initial file call in a promise and after that promise is resolved then you can call the translate provider, because the provider doesn't wait till the previous promise is resolved.  If i have a few minutes I will mockup some sample code.

Comment: You can always add the following line at the bottom of your call below your language set.  IE 
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('nl');
$translateProvider.forceAsyncReload(true);

Comment: If you are familiar with promises or willing to make a custom loader http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/13_custom-loaders you can make a promise in there and then load other stuff.  What I have done in the past is made a loading screen promise chain where I wait for the translations to load by default or a timeout of 2000 ms has occurred before I show the page loading.  This was because i had to support Hebrew and Arabic languages and my page layout would look weird if I had to flip it before I knew what language to load.

Answer (score 14):

As described in the [angular-translate documentation](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide) you should replace  `||` with `|` in the html file :

```
{{ "HOMETITLE" | translate }}
```

Hereafter a standalone snippet including the json translations :

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', [
  'pascalprecht.translate',
  'angularTranslate',
]); 

angular.module('angularTranslate', ['pascalprecht.translate'])
  .config(function($translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider ) {
    $translateProvider.translations('nl', {
      "HOMETITLE" : "Geweldige Whatsapp gesprekken.",
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('nl');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate/2.7.2/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate-loader-partial/2.7.2/angular-translate-loader-partial.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<body>
{{ "HOMETITLE" | translate }}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, the formatting error was stupid from me. The problem now is that it doesn't work with JSON files because of a race condition (see the other answer from James), do you know how I could solve that?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to a mixup between a JavaScript language construct and an AngularJS template string [interpolate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) expression.

Consider the following JavaScript expression:

```
var foo = bar || baz;
```

Depending on the value of `bar`, the expression `bar || baz` will return **either** `bar` or `baz`. When `bar` is *[truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)*, it will be returned; otherwise (when it's *[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)*) `baz` will be returned.

Given the following AngularJS interpolate expression: `{{ "HOMETITLE" || translate }}`, the expression evaluates to the value `"HOMETITLE"`, since that string literal is truthy.

However, the `translate` **[filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)** should be bound to your HTML template as follows `{{ "HOMETITLE" | translate }}`. Hence, the `translate` filter will be passed the key *'HOMETITLE'* as an argument and it should return the required text.